# How to take the result of an excel formula and drop it into a table

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of payments, they mostly use formulas. On a separate tab I want the results of some lines to transfer to a table and not be affected if I alter the original formula.Please help.

I havent tried anything yet as I dont know where to start

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste as values.

[image]

even with right click available

[image]

Or copy ctrl+C   and paste ctrl+v  and then press the little crl icon an choose values

[image]

And now while I'm writing to you, I learned this:

Ctrl+c  to copy

Ctrl+v to paste

Ctrl  to open the small menue in the cell

v   to paste as values